# Logic X Exporting Video (Issue)

Tags: sound-design, daw, logic-pro, film-sound-design

Does anyone else have issues with Logic X exporting video?

I import the video, compose sound around it, the export the video, but for someone reason, only part of the video is visable. I have the loop markers set correctly, but it always seems to glitch up.

For an example: If I have a 30 second clip and export it. 5 seconds will be white (or frozen frame) and the other 25 sec will play normal or, it starts off ok, but then the last few seconds freeze frame or don't show at all.

Here's how I export
File->Project Settings->Movie - audio to movie

The sound plays fine, but the video doesn't

Has anyone one else encountered this error?

Comment: have you checked the logic forums? this seems like a video issue, not a sound issue and it could be considered off topic..

Comment: I have checked the logic forums. I figured it would be on topic considering a lot of sound guys/gals use logic and write to picture. If it gets remove, then we'll know.

Comment: thanks for responding, don't worry it's not completely off topic.. what did you find on the logic forums? and more important what type of video container/codec did you use? mpeg etc?

Comment: No problem and thank you. In the logic forums I found threads with similar issues, but no resolution. Most weren't answered. The movie clip is an Mov. I have no problem exporting the vid in Logic 9, but with X, it's hit or miss (same video). Its so odd.